# Remove Style jQuery UI Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My question is if I can clear the styles in a specific case (in this case the accordion to place my own styles), but calling the jquery ui css to affect others if I want to show their styles.

```
clearStyle: true
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/x9N3P/

Comment: just manually override the styles for that particular accordion...

Comment: There will be a default option?, Well it was a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your goal is to override the default styles only under certain conditions (the question is a bit cryptic), you might try adding a CSS class to the container element dynamically whenever you want them overridden. Then you can apply your styles using something like the following:

```
.ui-accordion.override ul {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

And some sort of event to add the class:

```
$('#magicButton').click(function() { $('.ui-accordion').addClass('override'); });
```